# Can't indicate correct answers and incorrect answers in my quiz application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been puzzling over this for a bit now. Here's the code:

```
<ol>
  <% @quiz.questions.each do |question| %>
  <li> <%= question.content  %> </li>


    <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>

     <% @submitted_quiz.submitted_answers.each do |submitted_answer| %> 

    <% if(submitted_answer.content == answer.content && submitted_answer.got_correct) %>
    <li><span class ='correct-answer'><%= answer.content %> CORRECT </span></li>

    <% break %>

    <% elsif(submitted_answer.content == answer.content && submitted_answer.question.id == answer.question.id && submitted_answer.got_incorrect) %>
    <li><span class ='incorrect-answer'><%= answer.content %> INCORRECT</span></li>

    <% break %>

    <% elsif(submitted_answer.content != answer.content) %>
    <li><span class ='normal-answer'> <%= answer.content %> NORMAL</span></li>
    <% break %>

    <% end #  if statement%>

    <% end # submitted_answers.each do%>
    <% end # question.answers.each do |answer|%>

    <% end # @quiz.questions.each do %>
```

`submitted_answers` contains all the answers for the quiz that the user indicated was correct. For example:

```
Q: What color is the sun?
Blue
Yellow
Purple
Green
```

And if the user chose Yellow, `submitted_answers` would contain `Yellow` in `content:string` attribute, and also set the `got_correct` attribute to `true`. If the user chooses `Blue`, the same thing happens as before except now `got_correct` remains in its default state of `false` and another attribute, `got_incorrect`, is set to `true`. The logic for this is completed already and it works fine. My problem is that I want to display all the questions and answers for the quiz, and if the answer matches the one of the `submitted_answers` and the latter's `got_correct` is true, I indicate that the user correctly answered the question by highlighting the answer in green. If the answer matches one of the `submitted_answers` and the latter's `got_incorrect` is true, I indicate that the user incorrectly answered the question by highlighting the answer in red.

My code above isn't working because I keep iterating over a `submitted_answer` even after I have matched the `submitted_answer`to an `answer`. So, the code works for the first question and doesn't work for the remaining questions. How should I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean 'normal answer' ? Didn't get that case

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ol>
  <% @quiz.questions.each do |question| %>
  <li> <%= question.content  %> </li>


    <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>

        <% @submitted_quiz.submitted_answers.each do |submitted_answer| %> 

            <% if(submitted_answer.content == answer.content && submitted_answer.got_correct) %>
            <li><span class ='correct-answer'><%= answer.content %> CORRECT </span></li>

            <% break %>

            <% elsif(submitted_answer.content == answer.content && submitted_answer.question.id == answer.question.id && submitted_answer.got_incorrect) %>
            <li><span class ='incorrect-answer'><%= answer.content %> INCORRECT</span></li>

            <% break %>

            <% elsif(submitted_answer.content != answer.content) %>
            <li><span class ='normal-answer'> <%= answer.content %> NORMAL</span></li>
            <% break %>

            <% end #  if statement%>
            <% next %>
        <% end # submitted_answers.each do%>
    <% end # question.answers.each do |answer|%>

  <% end # @quiz.questions.each do %>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your problem is being caused because of what you might call misalignment between the `@quiz.questions.answers` and `@submitted_quiz.submitted_answers`.  For each question, and then each official answer, you're iterating through **every single one** of the user responses.  So the expected outcome would be running into a `break` after the first question.

If `@submitted_quiz.submitted_answers` is a parallel array to `@quiz.questions.answers`, you can make something like the following changes:

```
<ol>
  <% @quiz.questions.each do |question| %>
  <li> <%= question.content  %> </li>

    <% question.answers.each_with_index do |answer, index| 
       user_answer = @submitted_quiz.submitted_answers[index]
    %>

    <% if(user_answer.content == answer.content && user_answer.got_correct) %>
    <li><span class ='correct-answer'><%= answer.content %> CORRECT </span></li>

    <% break %>

    <% elsif(user_answer.content == answer.content && user_answer.question.id == answer.question.id && user_answer.got_incorrect) %>
    <li><span class ='incorrect-answer'><%= answer.content %> INCORRECT</span></li>

    <% break %>

    <% elsif(user_answer.content != answer.content) %>
    <li><span class ='normal-answer'> <%= answer.content %> NORMAL</span></li>
    <% break %>

    <% end #  if statement%>

    <% end # question.answers.each do |answer|%>

    <% end # @quiz.questions.each do %>
```